# fastai error predicting with exported/reloaded model: "Input type and weight type should be the same"

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, fast-ai

Whenever I export a fastai model and reload it, I get this error (or a very similar one) when I try and use the reloaded model to generate predictions on a new test set:

```
RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.cuda.HalfTensor) should be the same
```

Minimal reprodudeable code example below, you just need to update your `FILES_DIR` variable to where the MNIST data gets deposited on your system:

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *

# download data for reproduceable example
untar_data(URLs.MNIST_SAMPLE)
FILES_DIR = '/home/mepstein/.fastai/data/mnist_sample'  # this is where command above deposits the MNIST data for me


# Create FastAI databunch for model training
tfms = get_transforms()
tr_val_databunch = ImageDataBunch.from_folder(path=FILES_DIR,  # location of downloaded data shown in log of prev command
                                train = 'train',
                                valid_pct = 0.2,
                                ds_tfms = tfms).normalize()

# Create Model
conv_learner = cnn_learner(tr_val_databunch, 
                           models.resnet34, 
                           metrics=[error_rate]).to_fp16()

# Train Model
conv_learner.fit_one_cycle(4)

# Export Model
conv_learner.export()  # saves model as 'export.pkl' in path associated with the learner

# Reload Model and use it for inference on new hold-out set
reloaded_model = load_learner(path = FILES_DIR,
                              test = ImageList.from_folder(path = f'{FILES_DIR}/valid'))

preds = reloaded_model.get_preds(ds_type=DatasetType.Test)
```

Output:

> "RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type
>   (torch.cuda.HalfTensor) should be the same"

Stepping through the code statement by statement, everything works fine until the last line `pred = ...` which is where the torch error above pops up.

Relevant software versions:

Python 3.7.3
fastai           1.0.57
torch            1.2.0
torchvision      0.4.0

Comment: hm so if I comment out the `.to_fp16()` then the script above runs fine with no errors. And I think from this issue it looks like this is probably a bug?  https://github.com/NVIDIA/apex/issues/168

...but maybe I'm just missing the correct way to export/reload a model trained with fp16 precision...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer to this ended up being relatively simple:

1) As noted in my comment, training in mixed precision mode (setting `conv_learner` `to_fp16()`) caused the error with the exported/reloaded model

2) To train in mixed precision mode (which is faster than regular training) and enable export/reload of the model without errors, simply set the model back to default precision before exporting.

...In code, simply changing the example above:

```
# Export Model
conv_learner.export()
```

to:

```
# Export Model (after converting back to default precision for safe export/reload
conv_learner = conv_learner.to_fp32()
conv_learner.export()
```

...and now the full (reproduceable) code example above runs without errors, including the prediction after model reload.

Answer (score 2):

Your model is in half precision if you have `.to_fp16`, which would be the same if you would `model.half()` in PyTorch.

Actually if you trace the code `.to_fp16` will call `model.half()`
But there is a problem. If you convert the batch norm layer also to half precision you may get the convergence problem.

This is why you would typically do this in PyTorch:

```
model.half()  # convert to half precision
for layer in model.modules():
  if isinstance(module, torch.nn.modules.batchnorm._BatchNorm):      
    layer.float()
```

This will convert any layer to half precision other than batch norm.

Note that code from [PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/training-with-half-precision/11815/2) is also OK, but just for `nn.BatchNorm2d`.

Then make sure your input is in half precision using `to()` like this:

```
import torch
t = torch.tensor(10.)
print(t)
print(t.dtype)
t=t.to(dtype=torch.float16)
print(t)
print(t.dtype)
# tensor(10.)
# torch.float32
# tensor(10., dtype=torch.float16)
# torch.float16
```

Comment: Thanks Prosti, although it's still unclear to me how to adapt my fast.ai script above to get it to export/load/predict successfully using half precision. Also, the fast.ai documentation says `to_fp16()` should already leave the batch norm at fp_32: "Internally, the callback ensures that all model parameters (except batchnorm layers, which require fp32) are converted to fp16" https://docs.fast.ai/callbacks.fp16.html#to_fp16

Comment: `.to_fp16` will do the batch norm safe code. The thing you need to do is to convert your input to be half precision. This is what caused the problem. Use `.to(dtype=torch.float16)` on your input tensors.